# last login info in telnet session

Tags: linux, ssh, telnet

I am trying to print the last login info in a telnet session. how do i enable this?

I want the telnet session to display something like this

"Last login: Sun Dec 9 12:50:43 2007 from 192.168.0.6"

For ssh session , i have enabled the printlastlog in sshd_config file and i am able to get ssh session to print last login info.

Is there anything similar i need to do in telnet session?

I have checked /var/log directory, there are lastlog file and wtmp file.

Comment: in theory I suppose a telnet server could log it and display it to the client when the client connects. The q then may be if any of them do or can be made to, and I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `last` command is what it takes:

```
 > last | head -n 3
 my_name    pts/3        :0.0             Mon Sep  7 16:08 - 19:10  (03:02)    
 my_name    pts/3        :0.0             Mon Sep  7 15:56 - 16:05  (00:08)    
 my_name    pts/3        :0.0             Mon Sep  7 07:44 - 07:49  (00:05)
```

Does this not work for you??